# Getting runtime exception when trying to dynamically adjust size of UITableView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to increase the height of my UITableView whenever the user adds a new row to the table.  The code allows the user to successfully add rows to the tableView no problem, however, I am getting a runtime exception when I try to adjust the height of the table with it.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)addRow:(id)sender {

    ...

    CGFloat maxDynamicTableHeight = 250.0f;
    NSInteger numberOfSections = [self numberOfSectionsInTableView:self.myTable];
    CGFloat runningHeight = 0.0f;

    for (int section = 0; section < numberOfSections && runningHeight < maxDynamicTableHeight; section++) {
        NSInteger numberOfRows = [self tableView:self.myTable numberOfRowsInSection:section];
        for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows && runningHeight < maxDynamicTableHeight; row++) {
            NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
            NSLog(@"what is my path object? %@", path);
            runningHeight += [self tableView:self.myTable heightForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section]];
        }
    }

    CGRect frame = self.choiceTable.frame;
    frame.size.height = (runningHeight > maxDynamicTableHeight) ? maxDynamicTableHeight : runningHeight;
    self.myTable.frame = frame;
}
```

What I also am doing in my code is outputting the NSIndexPath object to see if it is valid, and this is what I get:

```
what is my path object? <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}
```

The runtime exception I get is:

> [MyViewController tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9d306aadb0
>   2015-10-12 01:02:09.300 munch[27412:5036398] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyViewController tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9d306aadb0'
>   *** First throw call stack:

Can anyone see what it is I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I am not sure where you are calling that `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`  because it doesn't seem to be in the code shown but it omits the `inSection:` parameter so you get an unrecognised selector exception

Comment: If you scroll to the right, it's there :-)

Comment: No, it is there in *that* code. The exception tells me that you are trying to call it somewhere else *without* inSection - I can tell from the method signature in the exception message

Comment: I see what you're saying.  My apologies.  I believe it is referring to this line:  [self tableView:self.myTable heightForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section]];  I'm providing the section parameter for the NSIndexPath object, but not for the heightForRowAtIndexPath method.  I checked, and the heightForRowAtIndexPath doesn't require a section parameter.

Comment: Oh,you are right. Sorry.  but still  the exception tells you that your view controller doesn't implement a method that matches that call that is being made

Comment: Ah.  Ok.  I didn't implement this method.  Thanks for pointing this out.  However, if my height is to be dynamic, what value should this method return?

Comment: Post your comment that I need to implement the method as a solution, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is telling you that your table view datsource hasn't implemented the method `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

If you implement this method then the exception will go away